# Origin: null CORS requests in AWS HttpApi (API Gateway v2)

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm trying to make a serverless API method implemented using AWS SAM HttpApi (aka API Gateway v2) to handle requests with "Origin: null" correctly.

I tried three obvious steps.

**Adding `AllowOrigins - null` into `CorsConfiguration` in `template.yaml`**

Gets rejected with "Invalid format for origin null (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400;"

**Adding a wildcard**

```yaml
Globals:
  HttpApi:
    CorsConfiguration:
      AllowOrigins: 
        - "*"
      AllowHeaders: 
        - Content-Type
      AllowMethods: 
        - POST
        - OPTIONS
```

This works as expected with origins that start with `http`, but if the request headers contain `Origin: null`, no CORS headers are present in the response.

**Removing `CorsConfiguration` altogether**

I've tried to instead return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the Lambda request handler, but it appears to be removed from the response. Apparently, it's a feature of API Gateway v2, although [its documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html) makes it sound like it's optional. Can API Gateway v2 filtering of the CORS headers returned by the application be disabled? Removing `HttpApi/CorsConfiguration` section from the `template.yaml` didn't have an effect.

Comment: Stop. You should never allow he `null` origin in your CORS configuration; doing so is insecure.

Comment: @jub0bs I don't have control over [the client side](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-apps/build-backend#handle-cross-origin-resource-sharing-(cors)), unfortunately.

Comment: Either way, you should not allow the `null` origin. Doing so will expose your users to cross-origin attacks.